# React in vscode not linting errors properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I recently changed my laptop and every day I find a new problem and no solution. I used to create a react app and if I forgot to return the jsx in a react component, I would see in chrome something like "Error: App(...) Nothing was returned from render .... etc. Don't remember if there was an error in vscode but I would swear there was too.

Now, I do that on porpuse, created a fresh react app with npx create-react-app and removed the return from App and do a console log in the component function. When I npm start, I can see the console log in dev tools, no error in vscode, no error in chrome. Just white screen and the terminal doesn't show any errors either!

In other projects I always use eslint + prettier + airbnb but tried to remove everything (except the plugins in vscode from eslint and prettier) and did a fresh create-react-app with nothing, same result, so I assume that's not the problem.

---

Also, I would like to also ask if my eslint config has any issue or everything is fine? Would you modify anything? Mostly for react.

Another problem, when I add "prettier/prettier": "error" in eslintrc to see all prettier errors, it forces me to do double quotes, even though my extension says single quotes and my .prettierrc file also do singleQuote true. The only solution is to remove the eslintrc rule but I can't see prettier errors anymore.

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "babelOptions": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
    },
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 13,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["prettier", "react", "react-hooks"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "react/function-component-definition": [
      "error",
      { "namedComponents": "arrow-function" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: since you are sure there was an error in Chrome, but not so sure about an error in VSCode - perhaps the only issue is that there's no error in Chrome now ... and since tehre's been a major release (103?) recently, it's probably one of those things Google breaks with every damned second release since 2012!